# How to sample from multiple chains with GPflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mcmc, gpflow, gaussian-process

I have recently started using gpflow to build a GP model. I used a Hamiltonian Monte Carlo to sample the posterior with a single chain.

My goal is to run multiple chains and perform convergence diagnostics.

This is my set up for one chain:

```
num_burnin_steps = ci_niter(100)
num_samples = ci_niter(500)


hmc_helper = gpflow.optimizers.SamplingHelper(
    model.log_posterior_density, model.trainable_parameters
)

hmc = tfp.mcmc.HamiltonianMonteCarlo(
    target_log_prob_fn=hmc_helper.target_log_prob_fn, num_leapfrog_steps=10, step_size=0.01
)

adaptive_hmc = tfp.mcmc.SimpleStepSizeAdaptation(
    hmc, num_adaptation_steps=10, target_accept_prob=f64(0.75), adaptation_rate=0.1
)


@tf.function
def run_chain_fn():
    return tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
        num_results=num_samples,
        num_burnin_steps=num_burnin_steps,
        current_state=hmc_helper.current_state,
        kernel=adaptive_hmc,
        trace_fn=lambda _, pkr: pkr.inner_results.is_accepted,
    )

samples, _ = run_chain_fn()
constrained_samples = hmc_helper.convert_to_constrained_values(samples
```

I cannot find any examples on how to modify this for multiple chains. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/mcmc/potential_scale_reduction) is the closest example I can find that does the same thing. Initial_state is altered to have 10 chains. To do the same with my example I would need to alter hmc_helper.current_state but cannot figure out the right way to do this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I am new to stack overflow so apologies if my question is not clear.

Thanks!

Comment: your setup isn't complete

Comment: Tensorflow-probability can sample multiple chains in parallel because all tfp distributions happily broadcast over leading dimensions. Unfortunately this is not the case in GPflow (see https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/issues/1204) as of now (version 2.1.2).

You can of course run the MCMC chain sequentially several times (simply initialize with different random states drawn from your prior - this should be straightforward), and perform the convergence diagnostics on that (more details on that would be a separate question).